# Using 'null' vs 'this' in apply or apply() and call() functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between using `this` and `null` as the `thisArg` context to the `apply()` and `call()` methods?

```
function getMax(arr) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
}

function getMax(arr) {
  return Math.max.apply(this, arr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) is a **static** function, so it doesn't matter what you pass as `this`, because `this` is not used.  So your functions are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks but suppose, instead of a stactic function some other function was there then what is the use of passing this or null and the difference , pardon me for being naive , would be of great help if explained.

Comment: @Harsh, from spec: [_The thisArg value is **passed without modification** as the this value. This is a change from Edition 3, where an undefined or null thisArg is replaced with the global object and ToObject is applied to all other values and that result is passed as the this value. Even though the thisArg is passed without modification, non-strict functions still perform these transformations upon entry to the function._](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-function.prototype.call)

Answer (score 0):

The signficance of using `this` is to set the current context when calling the method. For example:

```
function Human() {
    this.getMax = function getMax(arr) {
      console.log(this.constructor);
      return Math.max.apply(this, arr);
    }
}

var human = new Human();

human.getMax([1,2]);
```

Here, the console statement will out this.constructor as Human. Had it been otherwise, you would have got the context as window.

For the first case, when you pass null, it wont pass the context. This works here because Math.max expects paramters in comma seperated format a, b, c which is being handled when you do .apply.

Comment: Thanks gauravmuk , further I had query when null will not give any context then for what purpose it can be used because the main objective of apply is to give the context.